# background worker delegate & invokers

Tags: c#, delegates, backgroundworker, invoke

I have a background worker that does many GUI interactions, but my problem is that all of      those objects are in the main thread (as I know), and I need to invoke all of the all the    time, something that is making my code longer and less readable.
1) Do you know how can I create a generic method that will invoke those GUI elements.
2) Is there a more simple way to confront this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's just doing it wrong, you should never have to use Begin/Invoke in the BGW thread.  The ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events are meant to do this.  Focus on only generating data in the worker.  And update the UI with that data in the event handlers.

Comment: @HansPassant, How can I pass the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the BackgroundWorker you can [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx) and pass a percentage complete and an object. You could create a class to contain the data to pass to UI and then pass it as the object.

The [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) Event can manipulate UI Objects since it would be running in the UI Thread.

Example for your issue

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();

        items.Add("Starting");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(25, items.ToArray());

        items.Add("Halfway there");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(50, items.ToArray());

        items.Add("Almost there");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(75, items.ToArray());

        items.Add("Done");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100, items.ToArray());
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.AddRange((string [])e.UserState);
        this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }
```

The second argument in ReportProgress is an Object type.  you can put whatever you want in it and cast it to the proper type on the other side.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I need to send the generated data to the ProgressChanged, I have an array now that holds the data, but i don't know how to pass it to there+ I don't want to change the progress percent.

Comment: pass the array as the second argument in ReportProgress.  That maps to UserState in the ProgressChanged event.  Cast the UserState to your array.

Comment: Updated to demonstrate how to pass an array through the UserState variable.